# Symfony2 ajax: parametre + form ,binding error

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, post

i use Symfony 2 with ajax. I have 1 form, and when i click on i can send a form by ajax. I want to send 2variables:

exemple: ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url : "{{path('lcv_acceuil_form')}}",
type : "POST",
dataType : 'html',
data:
{
msg:    'form',
datas:  $('form#recherche').serialize()
},
cache:false,
success : function() ...
```

controller:

```
public function formAddAction()
{
        $entity = new FormA();
        $form = $this->createForm(new FormAType(),$entity);

        $request = $this->get('request');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
        {
            if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
                {
                    if ($request->request->get('msg') == "msg")
                    {
                      return (new Response('Msg')); 
                    }
                     else if ($request->request->get('msg') == "form")
                    {
                     $form->bind($request);
                     $em->persist($entity);
                     $em->flush();

                     return (new Response('Form added')); 
                    }
                else
                {
                    return (new Response('Its not Good!!')); 
                }
            }
    return (new Response('End'));

    }
        return $this->render('LCVAcceuilForm:Pages:formmanagement.html.twig',
         array('entity'=>$entity,'form'=>$form->createView()));
}
```

i have a problem with binding!!
my entity is empty...
when i change my "data" in ajax by just `$('form#recherche').serialize()` (only one variable) its work.

where is my mistake??

Comment: i solved a problem bu changing 
     data:
     {
      msg:    'form',
      datas:  $('form#recherche').serialize() 
      },
by

   data:$('form#recherche').serialize() + '&msg=form',

Answer (score 0):

I think you are packing data incorrectly.

First, collect the form data and then add `msg` item:

```
var data = $('form#recherche').serializeArray();
data['msg'] = 'form';
```

and then:

```
....
data: data
....
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is, correctly read your form data in Controller. If for example your `FormA` entity has properties (also getters and setters):

- name
- surname

you have to do something like this:

```
public function formAddAction()
{
$entity = new FormA();
$form = $this->createForm(new FormAType(),$entity);

$request = $this->get('request');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
{
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        if ($request->request->get('msg') == "msg") {
            return (new Response('Msg')); 
        } elseif ($request->request->get('msg') == "form") {
            $entity->setName($form['name']);
            $entity->setSurname($form['surname'])
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    return new Response('Success');
}

return $this->render('LCVAcceuilForm:Pages:formmanagement.html.twig',
    array('entity'=>$entity,'form'=>$form->createView())
);
```

}

You ajax should looks like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "{{path('lcv_acceuil_form')}}",
    type : "POST",
    dataType : 'html',
    data: $('form#recherche').serialize(),
   cache:false,
    success : function() ...
```

If your `FormAType` form name is for example: `formA` in twig you have to display inputs with proper form name and fields name. This should look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="formA[name]"/>
<input type="text" name="formA[surname]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="msg" value="test"/>
```

Of course your `FormAType` should have fields like above.

Comment: it dont work! i dont want to create a hidden input. i want to change the "msg". for exemple: if msg="form", controller know that its form, and if msg "complete", controller will reply by giving some more information.